# SQL how to prevent masking by like statement

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

I'm dealing with a masking issue with the `like` statement such that:

```
   case
   when name like 'PO_UTI_%' then 'UTI' 
   when name like 'PO_UTI_ADR_%' then 'UTI ADDRESS'
   when name like 'PO_OP_%' then 'OP' 
   when name like 'PO_OP_HH_%' then 'OP HH' 
   end newname
```

The newname UTI will be masking UTI ADDRESS and OP will be masking OP HH, how should I avoid this masking issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the conditions in a better order:

```
(case when name like 'PO_UTI_ADR_%' then 'UTI ADDRESS'
      when name like 'PO_UTI_%' then 'UTI' 
      when name like 'PO_OP_HH_%' then 'OP HH' 
      when name like 'PO_OP_%' then 'OP' 
 end) as newname
```

Actually, it may be better to order them by length:

```
(case when name like 'PO_UTI_ADR_%' then 'UTI ADDRESS'
      when name like 'PO_OP_HH_%' then 'OP HH' 
      when name like 'PO_UTI_%' then 'UTI' 
      when name like 'PO_OP_%' then 'OP' 
 end) as newname
```

This should help you ensure that there are no "masking" conflicts.

Comment: Is there a software to rank them by length...I'm defining close to 50ish newnames.

Comment: You can put the `when` statements in a spreadsheet and sort the column.

Answer (score 1):

just write the case in this order .

```
  case
   when name like 'PO_UTI_ADR_%' then 'UTI ADDRESS'
   when name like 'PO_UTI_%' then 'UTI'
   when name like 'PO_OP_HH_%' then 'OP HH'  
   when name like 'PO_OP_%' then 'OP' 
   end newname
```